# Retrieving the error that triggered the custom error page

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm new to error pages and have set up some error documents to handle errors like internal_server_error in a pretty fashion.  Is there a way of sending the error that sent the user to the error page to me in an email?

I know how to send emails in PHP but don't know how to retrieve the error that triggered the custom error page as this would be from the previous page.

I doubt I've explained that very well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure i understand correctly what you want but i'll try :

- error_get_last() will give you the last error. http://php.net/manual/fr/function.error-get-last.php
- Another way would be to store errors in a file and retrieve them when you need.

Comment: Thank you for trying @Elbarto.  Having done further research it seems I'm trying to do an impossible thing, a server 500 page so I will stop now.  Thanks again for your help.